# Using Mongo filter to query the _id of an object nested in an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, server

My db is a chat server, set up with User, Room and Message objects. This is for a class, so I'm trying to do it the way they want me to, and the Message object also exists within the Room's message property.

Here's an example:

```
{
            "_id": "6529f8191aa5efb066609b39",
            "title": "testroom2-edit",
            "description": "testdescription-edit",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "date": "Sat Oct 14 2023 02:01:15 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
                    "text": "message1",
                    "owner": "6529f7d81aa5efb066609b34",
                    "room": "6529f8191aa5efb066609b39",
                    "_id": "652a4acb8b929516368134ab"
                },
                {
                    "date": "Sat Oct 14 2023 02:01:21 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
                    "text": "message2",
                    "owner": "6529f7d81aa5efb066609b34",
                    "room": "6529f8191aa5efb066609b39",
                    "_id": "652a4ad18b929516368134b1"
                },
                {
                    "date": "Sat Oct 14 2023 02:01:25 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
                    "text": "message3",
                    "owner": "6529f7d81aa5efb066609b34",
                    "room": "6529f8191aa5efb066609b39",
                    "_id": "652a4ad58b929516368134b7"
                },
                {
                    "date": "Sat Oct 14 2023 02:01:29 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)",
                    "text": "message4",
                    "owner": "6529f7d81aa5efb066609b34",
                    "room": "6529f8191aa5efb066609b39",
                    "_id": "652a4ad98b929516368134bd"
                }
            ],
            "owner": "6529f7d81aa5efb066609b34",
            "__v": 0
        },
```

I'm trying to **use the filter** to grab the Room that has a message _id (in the array) entered as a parameter in Postman. The Room _id is also there, but I want to get it with the message _id.

Keeping it simple, my route is set up like this:

```
router.patch("/:roomId/:messageId", async (req, res) => {
```

This works, but I don't need it to.

```
const targetRoom = await Room.findOne({ "messages.room": req.params.roomId });
```

This always comes back 'null', and I'd like to understand why / what I'm doing wrong with the filter.

```
const targetRoom = await Room.findOne({ "messages._id": req.params.messageId });
```

Comment: Data type?  req.params.roomId is probably string, is `messages._id` actually ObjectId in the database?